# How to tackle noise with PI controller

Tags: control, pid-controller

Updated: I am not sure if the title fits my inquiry here but I will try to explain.

[image: Fig1.]

I have this system show in Fig1. It is a simple plant \$\frac{1}{as}\$ (expressed in the frequency domain). Then I use a simple controller such a a proportional controller (*Contr*) to follow a reference \$x_{ref}\$ (constant). The controller I use is a proportional controller, lets call it \$k\$ (the parameter of my controller could be easily computed by \$k=a/\tau\$, where \$\tau\$ is the time constant of design).

Then I have a modification of the previous system show in the Fig2.

[image: Fig2]

The addition is a delay with a signal adding and subtracting at the beginning and at the end of it, respectively (it is drew in black in the figure). Since \$b\$ is relatively small (in the range of 0.1-0.001) this addition could be neglected, having the first figure as a result. However, I notice that the addition produce high frequency noises in the output \$x\$. Although those noises are not big and therefore cause no much trouble. I would like to know if it would be possible to mitigate completely or reduce the noise by using a PI controller instead of a proportional only?

So far, I have reduce the system, and got a reduced system show in Fig. 3.

[image: Fig3]

Building that system in Matlab and using PID tuner tool, it provides the gains of the PI controller so that the noise in the output \$x\$ is reduced considerebly. But I dont know how to proceed analitically. I would appreciate any help or suggestion you can provide me. Thanks!

Ps: In case it is necessary some values of \$a,b,c\$ are a=27e-6,b=0.002,c=50, and the gain of the PID tool are kp=0.0479, ki=0.5339.

Comment: What does the bode plot look like?

Answer (score 1):

Bode plot will show lack of phase margin at unit gain. So the solution is to add phase lead compensation  (s/T + 1) near the unity gain T=1/ωo  for ωo being the unity loop gain frequency and adding 45 deg phase margin, so that the 2nd order system becomes a 1st order slope during the unity gain region. The frequency response should then have have more gain margin, less overshoot to a step input and less peaking in LPF breakpoint.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I am not expert in control and I was learning about bode plot, lead compensators and so on. Looking at the Fig3 I think it is clear that adding a lead compensator of (bs+b/(ac)+1) to the initial proportional controller will solve that problem. But I wanted to used a PI instead of a lead compensator as it seems it also can mitigate the noise. (side note: when I try to implement a lead compensator in simulink using a transfer function block, it gives me an error and say that the order of denominator must be greater than or equal to order of numerator)